# jQuery animate not properly calculating position when using percent in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I'm experiencing some odd behavior in Firefox when using jQuery to animate a fluid width position:absolute div. It works fine in Chrome. Strangely enough, I also tried older versions of jQuery, and it seems that this issue happens in jQuery 1.8.3 and newer.

You can view a fiddle of the issue here: http://jsfiddle.net/movwb2un/

CSS:

```
#wtf {
    background: #abf;
    border: 3px solid #007;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    right:50%;
    bottom: 30%;
    left: 0%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wtf"></div>
<button id="left">go left</button><button id="right">go right</button>
```

JS:

```
$('#left').click(function(){ $('#wtf').animate({'left':'0%','right':'50%'}); });
$('#right').click(function(){ $('#wtf').animate({'left':'50%','right':'0%'}); });
```

More test cases: http://jsfiddle.net/aau6vnfo/

Answer (score 0):

This definitely seems to be a bug, not sure if it is a jQuery or Firefox issue (or Chrome issue).

http://jsfiddle.net/ty517w5e/
Replacing `right : 0%` with `right : 0` in the second line seems to fix it.

Comment: The big downside is that it only fixes it when the `right` can be 0. I added some more test cases to make it slide off screen to left or right and those are broken too. http://jsfiddle.net/aau6vnfo/